# How to install mouse cursor?

Tags: mouse

Ok so, I downloaded this mouse cursor from open cursor library. The mouse cursor Taariq bolt.ani I dont know how to install or use this cursor! Please tell me how to use it, and I hope its not SUPER advanced stuff lol. Please help me!

Comment: This question was already answered. View this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/823656/where-are-cursor-icons-stored-on-ubuntu-16-04#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=The%20cursors%20are%20indeed%20installed,local%2Fshare%2Ficons%20folder.

Answer (score 11):

Installing cursors is really simple.

Install Tweak Tool with Software Centre or type commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

next you should copy folder with downloaded cursor theme.
to do, you need be root:

```
$ sudo nautilus
```

navigate to your downloads folder and look for archive with cursor, 
open archive and copy folder into **/usr/share/icons**

you are done, now start tweak tool to change your cursor:

```
$ gnome-tweak-tool
```

Comment: Instead of messing around using a nautilus opened with sudo privileges, it's probably best practice to put the cursor theme inside `~/.icons`