# Where are cursor icons stored on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: customization, cursor, cursor-theme

I’m trying to set up a new mouse cursor theme on my Ubuntu 16.04, and everything I look up keeps telling that me it stores the icons in the `/usr/share/icons` folder, but there's nothing in this folder at all (I do have show hidden files enabled). Am I doing something wrong?

Every tutorial on Ask Ubuntu, and every single help desk site, keeps telling me that the cursor icons are stored there, but they’re not there for some reason. All I want to do is figure out how to install a simple mouse cursor icon that I downloaded.

But how can I follow all the step by step tutorials online, when I can’t even complete step one since I can’t find where the cursors are stored?

Answer (score 13):

The cursors are indeed installed in the `/usr/share/icons` folder. User specific cursor themes can be installed in `~/.local/share/icons` folder. You might have got confused because of all those icon themes there.

Ubuntu treats icon themes and cursor themes similarly. However, the cursor theme folder includes an `index.theme` file and `cursors` folder. This differentiates them from regular icon themes.

---

#### Creating a custom cursor theme

Creating a custom cursor theme involves basically these three steps

1. First Create a directory naming it as the Cursor theme name. For example, `Clear`.
2. Create a folder named `cursors` that folder. You'll put your cursors files in this folder. The cursors should be named following specific naming guide line (Check the linked Ubuntu forum page for the guideline). You can also find the names from the default cursor theme `DMZ-White`.
3. Create a file named `index.theme` in the same level as `cursors` folder. The content of the file should be like these.

   ```
   [Icon Theme]
   Name=Clear
   Comment=Clear Cursor Theme
   ```

   The `Name` field's value is cursor theme name. It is *cAsE-SenSitiVe*. So, make sure this is exactly same as the folder name. The `Comment` field can contain any line of text.

**Tools:**

- You may find `xcursorgen` helpful. It converts a PNG image to Xcursor format file which can be used as a cursor. It comes with `x11-apps` package.

Additionally, Check these links for further help

- [Cursor themes - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cursor_themes#Create_links_to_missing_cursors)
- [Making a custom mouse cursor in ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426735/making-a-custom-mouse-cursor-in-ubuntu-12-04)
- [How to create your own mouse-pointer](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1440110) (Ubuntu forum)

Answer (score 6):

The top folder isn't `user` it is `usr`. This is what shows up in my plain vanilla Ubuntu 16.04:

[image: usr/share/icons]

Using Nautilus simply click on `Computer` on the left pane. Then in the main pane click `usr` then `share` then `icons`.