# How do I create a custom mouse pointer?

Tags: 16.04, unity, mouse-pointer

I want to create a custom mouse pointer on Ubuntu 16.04 from icons .How do I do it?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/823656/where-are-cursor-icons-stored-on-ubuntu-16-04